# Python requests: how to get the page that browser gets?

Tags: python-requests

I'm not a web programmer, sorry. :)  I'm just trying to implement an automatic login in a script.

Well, I open an URL that gets redirected two times.  When I open the page in my browser, the sequence looks like

```
https://login.mtc.md
https://login.mtc.md:18027/?host=https://login.mtc.md&uri=/
https://login.mtc.md:18027/browse.php
```

And browser finally opens the page I need to open.
But when I try to do that with Python **requests**:

```
r = requests.get (r'https://login.mtc.md')
```

it stops at the second URL. The response text contains only

```
<script language='javascript'> window.location = 'browse.php' </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to execute this javascript section and AFAIK, `requests` cannot do that. You may want to pick a look at, e.g., [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: Ah, I see: let a browser do the stuff.  A bit of overkill, but should work.  I'll try it, thanks!